# I downloaded a file and I don't know where it was saved?

Tags: windows-xp

I downloaded a 2.2gig file and I don't know where it is saved. I am trying to set up virtual box. When I go to import appliance it asks for a filename. I don't know where to find the file I downloaded. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: The easiest way (but dirty) way is to downloaded another file. Unless you manually changed the save location it will open a 'save as' dialog with the same location selected. Remember that location before closing the dialog.

Comment: What did you download it with? %userprofile%\downloads is a common place...

Comment: @user253695 did any of this help you?  Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try downloading the file again just to observe both where it is being saved by default and checking that directory for it, and also what the name of the file is.

Use the search function found under the windows start menu, you should be able to search by file type and/or when it was last modified to narrow the scope even not knowing the name

If that gets you nowhere, download a utility like WinDirStat (http://windirstat.info/), it will give you a visual representation of files on your hard drive, as well as ways to sort that information and parse through it.  If that file is a substantial size relative to your entire hard drive's contents it will be easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Press **Win+F** (or **Start** and **Search**) to bring up the Search Results window.
> 2. Click the link on the left side of the window: **All Files and Folders.**
> 3. From the **Look In** drop-down menu, choose **Local Disk (C:)**.
> 4. Click the chevron to expand the **What Size Is It** area.
> 5. Choose **Specify Size (in KB)**.
> 6. Choose **At Least**.
> 7. Type 2000000 in the **Size** text box.
> 8. You’re directing the Search command to scout out files larger than
>      2GB.
> 9. Click the **Search** button.